# uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain applet hang

Tags: java, applet, twain, image-scanner

I've an applet to communicate with scanner using TWAIN and uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain API.

In some circumstances (not dependent from version, in my case with 32bit OS) i have a problem during applet load, it seems to be in hang, TWAIN interface is slowly loaded and doesn't respond in the moment in which it appears.

At the end, i got this message

```
9uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainSource.enable:
    scan timed out. Close data source.
uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainSource.enable:
    scan timed out Close data source.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing **twaindsm.dll** into correct folder (depending on 32/64 bit OS version) solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Installing scanner driver may add more than one choice(for the same device) to the available twain sources. Try all of them and check if you have the same issue with all choices.

Comment: Scanner driver are already installed. Which other drivers do you refer to?

Comment: I installed a driver for my HP scanner (which is flat and batch scanner). when I go to my applet, I found two available sources for the same HP device. One of them cause exactly the issue you mentioned, the other one worked fine

Comment: Another thing, does this issue appeared in case of batch scanning?

Comment: It appears during applet load, as i said in main topic

Comment: do you call the method acquire in your applet load?

Comment: No, "acquire" method is called explicitly with another button

Answer (score 0):

mmscomputing  use TWAIN_32.DLL when the OS is 32bit **or the twain version is less than 2.0** While they use TWINDSM.dll when the system is 64bit **or twain version is 2.0**.

http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/uk/co/mmscomputing/device/twain/

I think your applet is hanging when using twain 2.0 scanners and working fine when using <2.0 scanners so to be sure try the following:

1- Copy the file C:\Windows\System32\TWAINDSM.dll to a safe place

2- Delete the file C:\Windows\System32\TWAINDSM.dll

3- Try the applet

I think your applet will work fine after that.